# Give sibbling element same "padding" as flexbox property justify-content: space-around

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sorry for murdering the title. But Im not sure how to summarize my problem.

I want the text in the footer to have the same padding as my list(to be exactly under). Is this possible?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dyLnbr4a/

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid darkgoldenrod;
}

aside {
  border: 1px solid wheat;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <picture>
      <img src="https://d2btg9txypwkc4.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/category/Kampanjer_1.jpg" alt="image description" style="max-width: 460px">
    </picture>
  </aside>
</section>
<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you edit the HTML?

Comment: @sol Yes I can!

Comment: Based on a dynamic width for `ul/li` and/or `img`, and the fact that `space-around` distribute the available space equally on each side of the elements, that is not possible using CSS. Script will be one solution, using a `table` another or use a different method to align the items. So the question is, what is the main goal? Is an exact left aligned (or should it be in the centered relative to the list) footer more important, than the padding pattern? ... And are the list items text (and footer) allowed to wrap?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `pseudoelement` on the footer to mimic the space occupied by the image. (this method won't really work if the image size is dynamic)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/47zp2mpg/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid darkgoldenrod;
}

aside {
  border: 1px solid wheat;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* default padding assigned to <ul> */
  padding-left: 40px;
}

footer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 330px;
  max-width: 460px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
      <li>
        bla
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <picture>
      <img src="https://d2btg9txypwkc4.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/category/Kampanjer_1.jpg" alt="image description" style="max-width: 460px">
    </picture>
  </aside>
</section>
<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```